# How to get last 30 days data in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am querying data for last 30 days and not getting expected result. Today is 2021-01-18 and last three days date is 2021-01-18 but I am getting only this month and year data not December how can i get?
My code is

```
$startDate = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDays(30);
$endDate = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
    return Auth::user()->invoices()
        ->whereBetween("invoice_date", [$startDate, $endDate])
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
        ->get();
```

and also try other solutions like this,

```
$date = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDays(30);
    return Auth::user()->invoices()
        ->whereDate("invoice_date", '>=', $date)
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
        ->get();
```

get same output my database table data is,

[image]

and display out is

[image]

Comment: `\Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDays(30)` is `2020-12-19` not `2020-12-18` that's why you're not getting any results before `2020-12-19`

Comment: Can you set this query how can i get it. Thanks

Comment: why? it's the right behavior. 30 days before today was  `2020-12-19`

Comment: But I am getting wrong result. this time i have multiple record record in database. 2021-01-11,2021-01-18, 2020-12-18,2021-01-01 and i am getiing only 2021-01-11,2021-01-18,2021-01-01 mean this year and month not privous year and month

Comment: What is the data type of `invoice_date` field in mysql. Did you use timestamp (or DateTime) or varchar?

Comment: It is dateTime in db

Comment: Its my bad. Only greater then 19 date will work i was testing data of 18 dec,

Answer (score 0):

Try below code it will help you:

```
$date = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDays(30);
$year = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->year;

return Auth::user()->invoices()
    ->where("invoice_date", '>=', $date)
    ->where("invoice_date", '>=', $year)
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```